# Django auto assign a value to a model field on_save in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am a bit lost again. I am a beginner in this. 
I have two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Name")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, default="+22123456789")
    ...

class Adress(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_lenght=200, default="City")
    ...
```

In my admin.py I edit them inline so on one form I can have all the person data and few of his addresses. This is important. I do need to have a relation of a single person to 1-3 addresses.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Adress
from .models import Person

class AdressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Adress

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AdressInline    
    ]

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Now ... the problem is that there is no way to create a list_display with fields from both models. For my understanding list-display is flat, and there is no where to put 3 values of same field on it. I would like to have a list looking like this:

```
list_display = ('name', 'phone', 'city')
```

So ... my idea is to create an extra field in model Person called 'maincity' that would not be editable by user, but would be filled automatically based on the value in Adress model. After we save the form. I have found something like this in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super(ArticleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

How to tell django to assign Adress.city to Person.maincity ?? *

*You might laugh, I am just learning.

Comment: `def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):` is this for `AddressAdmin` or `PersonAdmin`

Comment: No, this is plain example from Django Docs. But I would have to use it for `PersonAdmin`.

Comment: If a person has more than one addresses, which address' city will you save in Person.maincity? Or is it that the city will always be same for multiple addresses of same Person?

Comment: Good question .... No idea :( The last one ? I'm more stuck then I thought.

Comment: That's something your project requirements will dictate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the City values in both Person and Address models would lead to **Data Duplication**. While designing models or tables, we must avoid data duplication.

We can display the values of both Person and Address models in **AddressAdmin** list_display itself.

Define a method `nick_name` in AddressAdmin class with args as `self and obj`. Through obj args we can get the values of foreign key fields and **paste the method name in list_display**.

```
#models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#admin.py

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nick_name', 'city')

    def nick_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name.nick_name
```

Comment: This would work for AddressAdmin. But not for PersonAdmin right? I will have to give it a try, but how would inline behave then? Can I get same form with AddressAdmin list? My guess is not.

Comment: Ok, with a little bit of cheating I can get it to work "my way" :) Thank you.